# Is the current user an Administrator - Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-security

There are plenty of examples for Windows Desktop apps that will say whether or not the current user is an Admin.

Here are two

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wd8zba(v=vs.110).aspx

My problem is that I need to check within a Windows 8 Store App and they have a subset of the main .NET api. The stuff around Principals and Role are missing. 
The Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation class looked promising but that was a dead end.

Can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is useless, because Store Apps don't run when you have an account with full admin rights.

[image]

The Sandbox around the Apps requires UAC/ filtered rights. So your apps get never full admin rights and you can skip this check.

Comment: If I read you correctly you are saying a store app will not run when your account is a full administrator. Is that what you are saying? That means you are also saying that API, which requires admin rights, is never going work.

Comment: correct, store apps can never run as admin. You'll see this message: http://teamwindows8.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/uac-metro-app.png

Comment: I don't want to RUN as admin I wanted to be able to find if the current user IS an admin. You have said "Store Apps don't run when you have an account with full admin rights" yet I sit here on my 8.1 machine as a local admin running Window Store Apps just fine. After reading the EAS Compliance Docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.eascomplianceresults.Aspx) close I can in fact see that it will come back and tell me if I am not an Adminstrator so I no longer need any other way of checking

Comment: this makes no difference. With the UAC you get 2 tokens for admin users (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx). All applications run with the filtered token so all API calls will tell you limited/standard users. When you disable the UAC your app will no longer work. Why do you want to know?

Comment: Why do I want to know why the user is an Admin or not? I want to know because I do not want to call ApplyAsync (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientsecuritypolicy.applyasync.Aspx) with a user that is not an Admin. Doing so throws an Exception

Comment: this is terrible design. Add try/catch around it and handle the thrown exception correctly.